# Progress.CurrentTime !== Duration (React-Native-Video)

Tags: javascript, react-native, progress-bar

My issue if the following:

The **duration** of the video is **6.357** seconds. The **progress.currentTime** only goes to **6.154** and stops.

Since that **this.state.progress = 0.97 (not 1.0)**. As an outcome my *ProgressBar* doesn't go to the end. It stops on 0.97 position and **onProgressPress()** doesn't work.

Could someone please assist?

Here is my code:

```
export default class VideoComp extends Component {

state = {
    paused: false,
    progress: 0,
    duration: 0
}


onProgressPress = (e) => {
    const position = e.nativeEvent.locationX;
    const progress = (position / 250) * this.state.duration;
    this.player.seek(progress);
}

onMainButtonPress = () => {
    if(this.state.progress >= 1) {
        this.player.seek(0);
    };
    this.setState(state => {
        return {
            paused: !state.paused
        }
    })
}

handleEnd = () => {
    this.setState({
        paused: true
    })
}

handleProgress = (progress) => {
    this.setState({
        progress: progress.currentTime / this.state.duration
    });
}

handleLoad = (meta) => {
    this.setState({
        duration: meta.duration
    })
}

render() {
    const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const height = width * 0.5625;

    return(
        <View style = {styles.videoWrapper}>
            <Video
                source = {{uri: this.props.videoURL}}
                ref = {ref => this.player = ref}
                style = {{width: '100%', height}}
                paused = {this.state.paused}
                resizeMode = 'contain'
                onLoad = {this.handleLoad}
                onProgress = {this.handleProgress}
                onEnd = {this.handleEnd}
            />
            <View style = {styles.controls}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = {this.onMainButtonPress}>
                    <IconSimpleLine name = {!this.state.paused ? 'control-pause' : 'control-play'} color = {text} size = {20}/>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = {this.onProgressPress}>
                    <View>
                        <ProgressBar 
                            progress = {this.state.progress} 
                            width = {250}
                            height = {5}
                            color = {text}
                            borderColor = {text}
                            unfilledColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
                        />
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

                <Text style = {styles.duration}>
                    {secondsToTime(Math.floor(this.state.progress * this.state.duration))}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

***UPDATE***

I tried the next:

```
handleProgress = (progress) => {
    this.setState({
        progress: Math.floor(progress.currentTime) / this.state.duration
    });
}

handleLoad = (meta) => {
    this.setState({
        duration: Math.floor(meta.duration)
    })
}
```

The ProgressBar line now goes to the very end but it moves by a second. I mean, it moves a bit, stops on one second, moves a bit farther, stops on one second and so on. It doesn't move smoothly (each millisecond).

But it's not the correct solution.

Comment: Haven't you resolved this yet?

Answer (score 1):

the Video component has an `onEnd` prop. use that to update your state to 100%

Comment: If we set the duration at the end, the video is muted after playing for the first time. So this cannot be taken as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to user parseFloat() for calculation purpose.

in your question, I don't know which value is coming in float or in a fraction number but just for example use as this.

```
this.setState({
        progress: parseFloat(progress.currentTime / this.state.duration)
    });
```

and

```
const progress = parseFloat(position / 250)) * this.state.duration;
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.